# Dynamic SQL Pivot Query with Union All

Tags: sql-server, pivot, dynamic-sql, microsoft-dynamics

I have a static pivot query that tracks historical pricing (see below); it is union all of one table of current data, one table of historical data, and one related table.

I would like to convert it to a dynamic SQL pivot query so that I don't manually have to update the column heading dates all of the time, but I am having problems doing so. The data comes out of an accounting system (Microsoft Dynamics) running on SQL Server, and due to system limitations, I am unable to use ansi nulls/ paddings/ warnings and also unable to use quoted identifiers. Is there another way to create a dynamic sql pivot query?

Here is my current query. I want to replace the month-end dates with dynamic sql. I have view access to the data only.

```
SELECT ACTDESCR AS "ACCT NAME", concat(right(actnumbr_2,2), actnumbr_3) as PLU, [3/31/2015], [2/28/2015], [1/31/2015], [12/31/2015], [11/30/2014], [10/31/2014], [9/30/2014], [8/31/2014], [7/31/2014], [6/30/2014], [5/31/2014], [4/30/2014], [3/31/2014], [2/28/2014], [1/31/2014]
FROM
(SELECT A.ACTDESCR, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(B.YEAR1,B.PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1, A.actnumbr_2, a.actnumbr_3, B.PERDBLNC, A.ACTNUMBR_1
FROM TEST.dbo.table1 AS A   

LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST.dbo.TABLE2 AS b
ON (a.ACTINDX = b.ACTINDX)

UNION ALL

SELECT A.ACTDESCR, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(C.YEAR1,C.PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1, A.actnumbr_2, a.actnumbr_3, C.PERDBLNC, A.ACTNUMBR_1
FROM TEST.dbo.TABLE1 AS A

LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST.dbo.TABLE3 AS C
ON (a.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX)
) AS ST

PIVOT
(
SUM(PERDBLNC)
FOR DATE1 IN ([3/31/2015], [2/28/2015], [1/31/2015], [12/31/2015], [11/30/2014], [10/31/2014], [9/30/2014], [8/31/2014], [7/31/2014], [6/30/2014], [5/31/2014], [4/30/2014], [3/31/2014], [2/28/2014], [1/31/2014])

) AS PVT

WHERE ACTNUMBR_1 = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use T-SQL with dynamic SQL for this:

```
--VARIABLE TO HOLD DATES--
DECLARE @DATES NVARCHAR(500)
--VARIABLE TO HOLD CODE--
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

--TEMP TABLE TO FIND DISTINCT DATES--
CREATE #DATES (COLUMNVALS NVARCHAR(10))

--INSERT DISTINCT DATES INTO TEMP TABLE--
INSERT INTO #DATES
SELECT DISTINCT DATE1 FROM (
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR1,PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1
FROM TEST.DBO.TABLE2
UNION ALL
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR1,PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1
FROM TEST.DBO.TABLE3)

--CONCAT DATES INTO SELECT LIST--
SET @DATES = COALESCE(@DATES+', ','') + '[' + DATE1 + ']' FROM #DATES

--CREATE THE SELECT STATEMENT--
SELECT @SQL = '
;WITH ST AS (
SELECT A.ACTDESCR, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(B.YEAR1,B.PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1, A.ACTNUMBR_2, A.ACTNUMBR_3, B.PERDBLNC, A.ACTNUMBR_1
FROM TEST.DBO.TABLE1 AS A   
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST.DBO.TABLE2 AS B
ON A.ACTINDX = B.ACTINDX
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ACTDESCR, EOMONTH(DATEFROMPARTS(C.YEAR1,C.PERIODID,1),0) AS DATE1, A.ACTNUMBR_2, A.ACTNUMBR_3, C.PERDBLNC, A.ACTNUMBR_1
FROM TEST.DBO.TABLE1 AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST.DBO.TABLE3 AS C
ON A.ACTINDX = C.ACTINDX)
SELECT ACTDESCR AS "ACCT NAME", CONCAT(RIGHT(ACTNUMBR_2,2), ACTNUMBR_3) AS PLU, '+@DATES+'
FROM ST
PIVOT
(
SUM(PERDBLNC)
FOR DATE1 IN ('+@DATES+')
) AS PVT
WHERE ACTNUMBR_1 = ?'
--PRINT IT TO SEE WHAT IT'S DONE--
PRINT @SQL
--EXECUTE IT--
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately, I am using an external data connection in Excel to return the data to return the data from the database, which doesn't allow for the use of temporary tables.

Comment: In your original post it says the data came from a Dynamics CRM running SQL Server.... There's no limitations to anything if you look hard enough, alot of things I believed were impossible are now possible thanks to other people's persistance and research. I'd reccomend you didn't use Excel as an external data source, and rather use SQL Server and SSRS to create your matrix report. It's much simpler than what you're trying to accomplish here.